# How to format HTML code?

Tags: html

I was wondering if there is a quick way to simply align all my `html` codes to the left. so if I have coding that looks like below can look like further below.

```
<form role="form">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">Goal Description:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="gd"></textarea>
</div><div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">Performance Challenge:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="pc"></textarea>
</div><div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">Strategy:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="Strategy"></textarea>
</div><div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">Target:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="Target"></textarea>
</div>
```

this is what i want to look like when am working with it.

```
<form role="form">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="comment">Goal Description:</label>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="gd"></textarea>
</div><div class="form-group">
<label for="comment">Performance Challenge:</label>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="pc"></textarea>
</div><div class="form-group">
<label for="comment">Strategy:</label>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="Strategy"></textarea>
</div><div class="form-group">
<label for="comment">Target:</label>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="Target"></textarea>
</div>
</form>
```

I know about `ctrl + shift+ F`, I don't like the way that format is set either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are many online tools that align your HTML code properly. Just Google it (HTML Code Format).

Comment: In most text editors, you can select all (Ctrl + A) and then hit "Shift + Tab" a few times. That should move everything back to the left.

Comment: It also depends on your editor, but you didn't specify one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try highlighting your code and doing shift+tab

Comment: Thanks bud, that helps to some extent. but it still doesn't align all the to left.

Answer (score 3):

I would format it like this:

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Goal Description:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="gd"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Performance Challenge:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="pc"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Strategy:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="Strategy"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Target:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="Target"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

Both of the examples you provided contain poor formatting which makes it harder to read.

Comment: I don't care what looks easy to read to somebody, I am only looking to see if there is any command just like "ctrl + shift + F" that can align all html code in one line.

Comment: No, there is no shortcut to make your code have poor formatting, that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Maybe someone like you might have said the same thing about "ctrl + shift + F" formatting, but then rest of the community started liking it :)